# SignalR on Azure - 502 error on handshake

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I've got a site running on Azure with the following components:

- Mvc 5.1.2
- SignalR 2.0.2

When my page loads, SignalR calls `$.connection.hub.start()`. On my local and on an old VPS this is fine, but when I go to Azure I get:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.example.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=…7Au%2FeIQQh&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22projecthub%22%7D%5D&tid=9' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502`

WebSockets is switched on, and .NET v4.5 is active. I've added logging and it's falling over at:

[image: SignalR - 502 error]

[image: The error]

I have no clue why __DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule is failing. Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution - simple `web.config` change. Add the following:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why this fixes it? I'm getting a 403 error and wondering if this is related

Comment: The versions of the libraries I was using were only compatible with .NET 4.5. Your 403 error is something else - an authorization issue. Does yours work with anonymous access?

Comment: I'm using Forms Authentication and when logged out signalR works - at least no errors on WebSockets, but when I'm logged in, I get the 403 - not sure why that is - any ideas?